# Remove Words step by step from Left to Right in PHP String

Tags: php, string

I have a string and I want to remove words from its left to right step by step.

```
$n = 'Dettol Antibacterial Surface Cleansing Wipes';
$arr = str_word_count($n, 1);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++) {
  echo $arr[$x].'<br />';
}
```

What I want is to get 4 strings out of it removing words left to right.

```
string1= Antibacterial Surface Cleansing Wipes
string2= Surface Cleansing Wipes
string3= Cleansing Wipes
string4= Wipes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty way is to use `explode`, remove first element by `array_shift` and then `implode`.

```
$n = 'Dettol Antibacterial Surface Cleansing Wipes';
$words = explode(' ', $n);

while (!empty($words)) {
    array_shift($words);
    echo implode(' ', $words) . '<br>';
}
```